# Backblaze B2 jQuery file upload CORS error

Tags: jquery, post, cors

I'm trying to upload file to Backblaze B2 storage using jQuery. File content is being read directly from form:

```
var file = document.getElementById('file_input').files[0];
```

and after getting all necessary headers I finally write POST request:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authToken);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Bz-File-Name', fileName);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Bz-Content-Sha1', sha1);

    xhr.open("POST", uploadUrl, true);

    xhr.send(file);
```

Unfortunatelly I get CORS error (missing CORS header and blocked remote request to url). On Amazon S3 there was an option to set up CORS policy. On Backblaze I do not see any. Is there a possibility to send file another way or if not should I ask Backblaze B2 support team for solution?

Just to note: for example using urllib2 with python and default backblaze B2 turtorial everything went fine and sample text file was successfully uploaded.

Comment: B2 have not support CORS header yet. But, it will support in a future time.  https://help.backblaze.com/hc/en-us/articles/114094192774-Does-B2-have-CORS-headers-support-